# Error installing Turicreate on ubuntu python 3.8.2 on pip

Tags: python-3.8, ubuntu-20.04, turi-create

```
   ==================================================================================
        TURICREATE ERROR

        If you see this message, pip install did not find an available binary package
        for your system.

        Supported Platforms:
            * macOS 10.12+ x86_64.
            * Linux x86_64 (including WSL on Windows 10).

        Support Python Versions:
            * 2.7
            * 3.5
            * 3.6
            * 3.7


        Another possible cause of this error is an outdated pip version. Try:
            `pip install -U pip`

        ==================================================================================
```

This is the message I get after I type the command "pip install turicreate".

I am using ubuntu 20.4 and have python 3.8.2 installed on my system

Answer (score 4):

Turicreate doesn't support Python 3.8 yet. You have to use an earlier python version (e.g 3.7) to get turicreate working.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a virtual envirnment with any of the supported versions and then install turicreate. It works fine on Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 16.04 and is a good alternative for using turicreate as long as python3.8 support is not added.

Install any of the supported python versions and note its installation path (the installation folder is usually /usr/bin/ but it may vary).  Install virtualenv with `pip install virtualenv`. Navigate to your project and then create the virtual environment inside the project folder with `virtualenv -p /path/to/python/installation venv`.

I created it with python3.6, so for me it was `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 venv`. Then activate the new virtual environment by typing in `source venv/bin/activate`. Check the python version with `python --version`.

Then proceed to install turicreate.

After you are done with your work, deactivate the virtual environment with the `deactivate` command